# Check return value in FluentAssertion exception syntax

Tags: c#, nunit, nsubstitute, fluent-assertions

I'd like to check the return value from the method by *FluentAssertion* syntax. Please consider the following snippet:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    Task<int> DoSomething();
}

public class Bar
{
    private readonly IFoo _foo;
    private static int _someMagicNumber = 17;

    public Bar(IFoo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }

    public async Task<int> DoSomethingSmart()
    {
        try
        {
            return await _foo.DoSomething();
        }
        catch
        {
            return _someMagicNumber;
        }
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class BarTests
{
    [Test]
    public async Task ShouldCatchException()
    {
        // Arrange
        var foo = Substitute.For<IFoo>();
        foo.DoSomething().Throws(new Exception());
        var bar = new Bar(foo);
        Func<Task> result = () => bar.DoSomethingSmart();

        // Act-Assert
        await result.Should().NotThrowAsync();
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task ShouldReturnDefaultValueWhenExceptionWasThrown()
    {
        // Arrange
        var foo = Substitute.For<IFoo>();
        foo.DoSomething().Throws(new Exception());
        var bar = new Bar(foo);

        // Act
        var result = await bar.DoSomethingSmart();

        // Assert
        result.Should().Be(17);
    }
}
```

My goal is combining those two tests into the new one, but I'd like to preserve the fluent assertion check: `result.Should().NotThrowAsync();`

So my question is how to check in the first test that the return value is `17` in my example?

Comment: You are catching and swallowing the exception so there is nothing to check. Once the exception is caught it will return 17

Comment: Yes, because it's a simplified example. The purpose of this code is to demonstrate my requirement.

Comment: Yes but the first test serves no purpose. The successful completion of the second test implies that the exception was caught so there is nothing to combine or check

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The current version of Fluent Assertions (5.5.3) does not distinguish between `Func<Task>` and `Func<Task<T>>`.
Both types are handled by `AsyncFunctionAssertions`, which assigns it to a `Func<Task>` and hence looses the return value for `Task<T>`.

One way to circumvent this, is to assign the return value to a local variable.

```
[Test]
public async Task ShouldCatchException()
{
    // Arrange
    var foo = Substitute.For<IFoo>();
    foo.DoSomething().Throws(new Exception());
    var bar = new Bar(foo);

    // Act
    int? result = null;
    Func<Task> act = async () => result = await bar.DoSomethingSmart();

    // Act-Assert
    await act.Should().NotThrowAsync();
    result.Should().Be(17);
}
```

I've created an [issue](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/990) on the Fluent Assertion issue tracker.

**edit:**

Fluent Assertions 6.0.0 added support for `Task<T>`, so you can continue asserting on the result of `DoSomethingSmart`.

```cs
// Arrange
var foo = Substitute.For<IFoo>();
foo.DoSomething().Throws(new Exception());
var bar = new Bar(foo);

// Act
Func<Task<int>> act = () => bar.DoSomethingSmart();

// Act-Assert
(await act.Should().NotThrowAsync()).Which.Should().Be(17);
```

There's also a new neat helper `WithResult` for async methods to avoid the extra set of parentheses.

```cs
// Arrange
var foo = Substitute.For<IFoo>();
foo.DoSomething().Throws(new Exception());
var bar = new Bar(foo);

// Act
Func<Task<int>> act = () => bar.DoSomethingSmart();

// Act-Assert
await act.Should().NotThrowAsync().WithResult(17);
```

Comment: The solution in the edit doesn't work if you specify a type like `NotThrowAsync<Exception>()` as it doesn't have the extension. Removing the type works.